# Django pass object to model of another form

Tags: python, django

I have implemented a Python form/view/template that lets you configure different notifications for a product:

models.py

```
class PNotification(models.Model):
    add = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Receive messages when an engagement is 
    added')
    delete = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Receive 


class Product(models.Model):
```

forms.py

```
class PNotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PNotification
        exclude = ['']


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

The PNotification has an own view and template:

```
<h3> Edit Notifications for {{ product.name }}</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% include "dojo/form_fields.html" with form=form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When I call the page (edit/product_id/notifications) to edit an products notifications, the `h3` is set correct, so the product is passed to the form/template.

My problem is: I need to link PNotification with a product.

How can I pass `product.id` to my `PNotificationForm` so I can save it there? This field should be the primary key of PNotification.

### Edit

Here is my view.py:

```
def edit_product_notifications(request, pid):
    prod = Product.objects.get(pk=pid)
    logger.info('Editing product')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pnotification = PNotificationForm(request.POST, instance=prod)
        if pnotification.is_valid():
            pnotification.save()
            logger.info('saved')
        
    else:
        pnotification = PNotificationForm()
        if pnotification.is_valid():
            pnotification.save()
            logger.info('saved')

logger.info(PNotification.objects.get(id=1).msteams)
logger.info('returning')
return render(request,
              'dojo/edit_product_notifications.html',
              {'form': pnotification,
               'product': prod
               }).
```

I am passing the product id and then getting it from `objects.get()`.

Comment: Show us the view.py

Answer (score 1):

In `urls.py` the path to that view needs to have `<int:pk>`. The path would look like this `edit/<int:pn_pk>/notifications`

In your view you need to get the `kwargs` which is the argument passed by the url.

In a function based view:

```
def your_view_name(request, pk):
    # use pk how you want.
    PN = PNotification.objects.get(pk=pn_pk)
    return render(...)
```